# Search Functionality- How to display the Filtered data into listview

Tags: java, android, listview, widget

I had parsed the data from website and made it to display in the listview this is my 2nd activity, in 1st activity there is a edittext and search button, after giving the keyword in editext based on that keyword able to get the related search results in toast, but i want it to be displayed in listview, this is the code part.

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    JSONArray posts;


    //ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://www.example.com/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";


    static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
    static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
    static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
    static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
    static final String KEY_URL = "url";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
        //this will be used in the custom adapter
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
        try {
            posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                String url = null;
                String slug = null;
                try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for (int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, id);
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
                map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
                map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
                map.put(KEY_URL, url);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
        searchResults = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);


        // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //get the text in the EditText
                String searchString = searchBox.getText().toString();
                int textLength = searchString.length();

                //clear the initial data set
                searchResults.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
                    String playerName = songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                    if (textLength <= playerName.length()) {

                        //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                        if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0, textLength)))
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerName, 1).show();
                        searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {


            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: cant you just clear your adapter and set the filtered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code, Surely you will the output

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                    searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                    textLength=searchString.length();
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                   playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();
                  System.out.println("player name "+playerName);
                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){
                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength))){
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                    System.out.println("the array list is "+songsList.get(i));
                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, searchResults);   

                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                      }


                   }
                   if(searchResults.isEmpty()){
                       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "No Items Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                                  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                                  toast.show();
                   }
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {
                 System.out.println("before changed");

                   }

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                                               System.out.println("after changed");
                   }
                  });
```